# Multiple letters in one word in SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-like

I recently have started learning SQL however I have came across a problem I can't solve. The question I am being asked is "Find the countries that have three or more a in the name" meaning I need to find countries with 3 or more (a)'s in them. How do I go about entering this into my search.

I am pretty sure it will start with something like this (what I have below) but I am not sure what to add in after like. My tables name is called name.

WHERE name LIKE

Bahamas will be one of my outputted answers, but what do I need to enter to get that?

Comment: accualy i never tried this and that's intresting if it can be done(i'm not with my computer so i dont have the tools to test it : WHERE name LIKE '%a%a%a%'

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Case sensitive or insensitive? (Is Afghanistan supposed to be returned?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple but working fine :)

```
WHERE name like '%a%a%a%'
```

Comment: How can I answer the or more part?

Comment: this answers the or more part, it will give you each country that its name has at least 3 A's

Comment: as Sagi's said it will give you the result: "3 or more than 3" with this query